# Scroll Outer Scroll View Before Inner Scroll View - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

**Goal**

[image: layout]

When user tries to scroll the recycler view, the outer view (white view) should scroll up (or expand) to reveal more of the recycler view.

---

**What I've tried so far**

1. **Nested Scroll View**: I placed the white view inside a nested scroll view. This resulted in the recycler view getting priority while scrolling. So what resulted was that the recycler view scrolled to the end of the list first, after which the white view scrolled up to reveal more of the recycler view. I've tried a few setting isFocusable and isFocusableOnTouch on the nested scroll view and nested scroll view's linear layout.
2. **Translate Y** of the white view when recycler view is scrolled: Here I set on an on scroll listener on the recycler view and when the view is scrolled I also `translatedY` of white view by `dy`. This almost achived what I wanted. But when recycler view is scrolled slowly the items in the recycler view get "glichy" (the jump positions erratically).

The code behind this:

`var yPos = 200`

```kotlin
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        yPos -= dy
        if (yPos >= 0)
            whiteView.animate().translationY(yPos).duration = 0
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think better way use CoordinatorLayout, here you can see example: https://blog.mindorks.com/using-coordinator-layout-in-android